# Python Selenium Scroll to Bottom Google Photos Album

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am attempting to build a Raspberry Pi powered digital photo album utilizing Google Photos slideshows.  Ideally, I would like to be able to automate, via Selenium, the login process and then use BeautifulSoup to parse the html source for each image's unique url.

Google Photos seems to load ~12 images at a time (may be more/less based on image orientation) which makes obtaining the list of all image urls a bit more difficult.

I have attempted to use variations of the following in order to scroll through the loading of images:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Unfortunately, that code does not cause FireFox to scroll.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.  I have included my obfuscated code for review:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# print(driver.current_url)
driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin? sacu=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fphotos.google.com%2Flogin&hl=en#identifier')
# print(driver.current_url)
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('Email')
elem.send_keys('******')
elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('Passwd')
elem.send_keys('******')
elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(10)
driver.get('direct link to shared album')
time.sleep(5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,   document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Comment: What about `driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);`? I use the "page down" key when for some reason I'm not able to scroll.

Comment: @Y-BCause, OP asks for a `Python` solution

Comment: @Daniel, Why you need to scroll the page? There is no `XHR` and all images are initially available. You can just use `driver.get('direct link to shared album')`, `driver.page_source` and you should get proper `HTML` for following `bs4` parsing

Comment: @Andersson, unless I'm missing something, when I view the page_source from the album, only the first 12 images are included.  It appears their class names are "RY3tic" and the `href` for each begins with "./share/" because it is a shared album.  When I parse the page_source and look for the classes or the urls, only 12 return.  Interestingly, when I have manually scrolled to the bottom and viewed page_source, the original structure is there, yet the urls and content have changed.

Comment: @Daniel, Yeap. After I've added some more files, I can see your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, asking the `driver` to switch to the 'active element' produced undesirable results.  When I sent the `PAGE_DOWN` key, nothing would happen.  A solution for this problem was realized when I asked `Selenium` to find an element by tag name.  I was able to specify that I wanted to select the `body` of the site and then send the `PAGE_DOWN` key.  The solution appears below.

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Y-B Cause has mentioned, you can try `Keys` to solve your issue:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.switch_to_active_element().send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I add your suggested code, I'm given the following error:

`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'send_keys'`

Comment: When I execute the code up to Selenium tries to send the `PAGE_DOWN` key, when I manually press Page Down, the address bar opens and the focus switches to a stored URL that appears beneath the current page's URL.  Is it possible that Selenium is not switching it's 'focus' to the body of the webpage before trying to send the `PAGE_DOWN` key?